# Why this for loop PHP is super slow?

Tags: php, for-loop

### Why this for loop PHP is super slow?

I've tried minify this for loop as much as I can but error debugger cannot find issues here? Using code below on the website, page response is 30 sec on first load and 8 sec on 2nd, 3rd.

```
$modules_concat = "(CONCAT(',', `site_id`, ',') REGEXP ',(1|2),' AND m_type='my_table_name)";
$b2_s_v_a = '';

  for ($i = 1, $j = 168; $i <= 168, $j >= 0; $i++, $j--) {

    if ($i < 25) {
      $time_lang_for_start = $i+662;
      $time_lang_for_day = $lang['user_login_2'];
      $b2_time_hour = ($j-144)." HOUR AND HOUR(date_added) = ".($i-1);
      $b2_time_day = 'monday';
    } elseif ($i < 49) {
      $time_lang_for_start = $i+638;
      $time_lang_for_day = $lang['user_login_3'];
      $b2_time_hour = ($j-120)." HOUR AND HOUR(date_added) = ".($i-25);
      $b2_time_day = 'tuesday';
    } elseif ($i < 73) {
      $time_lang_for_start = $i+614;
      $time_lang_for_day = $lang['user_login_4'];
      $b2_time_hour = ($j-96)." HOUR AND HOUR(date_added) = ".($i-49);
      $b2_time_day = 'wednesday';
    } elseif ($i < 97) {
      $time_lang_for_start = $i+590;
      $time_lang_for_day = $lang['user_login_5'];
      $b2_time_hour = ($j-72)." HOUR AND HOUR(date_added) = ".($i-73);
      $b2_time_day = 'thursday';
    } elseif ($i < 121) {
      $time_lang_for_start = $i+566;
      $time_lang_for_day = $lang['user_login_6'];
      $b2_time_hour = ($j-48)." HOUR AND HOUR(date_added) = ".($i-97);
      $b2_time_day = 'friday';
    } elseif ($i < 145) {
      $time_lang_for_start = $i+542;
      $time_lang_for_day = $lang['user_login_7'];
      $b2_time_hour = ($j-24)." HOUR AND HOUR(date_added) = ".($i-121);
      $b2_time_day = 'saturday';
    } elseif ($i < 169) {
      $time_lang_for_start = $i+518;
      $time_lang_for_day = $lang['user_login_8'];
      $b2_time_hour = $j." HOUR AND HOUR(date_added) = ".($i-145);
      $b2_time_day = 'sunday';
    }

    $b2_n_o = 'test';

    $time_lang_for_get = $lang["user_login_$time_lang_for_start"];
    $time_ready_ch = 'time_ready_for_'.$i;
    $$time_ready_ch = $time_lang_for_day.', '.$time_lang_for_get;

    $b2_ch_v = 'b2_g_v_'.$i;
    $$b2_ch_v = $db->QueryGetNumRows("SELECT * FROM m_z_analytics WHERE $modules_concat AND date_added BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK AND NOW() - INTERVAL $b2_time_hour AND DAYNAME(date_added) = '$b2_time_day'");

    $b2_s_v_a .= ${"b2_g_v_$i"};
    if ($i) {
      $b2_s_v_a .= ',';
    }

  }
```

Example text.

Comment: Probably because your query is cached by the database, then on the 2nd, 3rd run seems to be faster

Comment: @FelippeDuarte I have the same Query in different for-loops and works fast, but with this I have problem.

Comment: You could do a `SELECT COUNT(col_name)` rather than a `SELECT *` as that is unnecessary data retrieval if all you want is the number of rows returned

Comment: You could prepare the query ONCE and use parameters and bind the variables on each execution. That would do the query compile and optimise steps once per script rather than once per iteration

Answer (score 2):

The most likely cause is your database query as you are calling it 168 times. Do you need to get all columns (SELECT *) in each? If not, specify the ones you need. You could also try to get all the data in less calls and parse how need afterwards.